# Is it possible to host a service like Dropbox on your own server with almost as good service?

Tags: windows, backup, dropbox

What if I have just made an important change and messed something up? Is this part of Dropboxes functionality?

I am considering hosting a Dropbox myself for own usage on a virtual machine, so I can also have back-ups and have more than 2GB in space.

Can iFolder offer this functionality? Is there even software available that allows to be self-hosted and offers remotely as good functionality?

Comment: You can get a lot more than 2GB with Dropbox. And yes, Dropbox has rollback functionality if you screw something up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only one I know off is [SparkleShare](http://sparkleshare.org/). It's brand new and a heavy beta, approach with caution. THey are still working on Windows-clients but OSX & Linux are "workable".

Comment: ooooooooooooh good to know thank you thank you thank you

Comment: SpacemanSpiff - if you like an answer you should vote it up, or even accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

iFolder doesn't offer versioning functionality, like Dropbox or Subversion. You can just restore manually a backup from your iFolder server if you have some issue. Another possibility is to use [SVN over an iFolder](http://www.dopefish.de/archives/1025) folder.